# update cookie value in php

Tags: php, arrays, cookies, store, setcookie

I am converting the array into cookie by php serialize function

```
$PromoteuserId='1';
$PromoteProductId='2';
$PromoteBrandId='3';
$PromoteProductArray = array("PromoteuserId"=>$PromoteuserId,
                            "PromoteProductId"=>$PromoteProductId,
                              "PromoteBrandId"=>$PromoteBrandId
                        );

$Promotedcart[] = $PromoteProductArray;

setcookie("Promotedcart", urlencode(serialize($Promotedcart)), time()+604800,'/');
```

And when the cookie is created then i am using the unserialize php function.

```
print_r(unserialize(urldecode($_COOKIE['Promotedcart'])));
```

I need to update the cookie value. E.g. - I need to search for PromoteProductId value is exit in the cookie if then it will update the cookie value coorespond to PromoteProductId .
could guide me how i can update the value?

Comment: Please do not use `unserialize` on user-submitted data. This is easily exploitable with object injection using PHP's __wakeup and __destruct methods. You can use `json_encode/json_decode` instead of `serialize/unserialize`. https://www.owasp.org/index.php/PHP_Object_Injection

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply store the unserialized cookie into a variable then reset the cookie?

```
$array = unserialize(urldecode($_COOKIE['Promotedcart']));  
$array[0]["PromoteuserId"] = "New";

setcookie("Promotedcart", urlencode(serialize($array)), time()+604800,'/');
```

Answer (score 1):

this link best simplify 
using Serialize and Unserialize data

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9032007/arrays-in-cookies-php/9032082#9032082
```